# LCD 16x2 Showing no text

Tags: arduino, lcd

I an trying to connect a 16x2 LCD text module with Arduino and it continuously shows only the green backlight. My code is correct and my connections are also correct. I tried the same project on Proteus and it works fine.

Thanks for everyone issue is solved..i buy new LCD and everything is fine.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h> 

LiquidCrystal lcd(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7);

void setup() { 
   lcd.begin(16,2); 
}

void loop() { 
    lcd.print("Sanjeev"); 
    delay(3000);  
    lcd.setCursor(2,1);
    lcd.print("LCD is working"); 
    delay(3000); 
    lcd.clear(); 
    lcd.blink(); 
    delay(4000); 
    lcd.setCursor(7,1); 
    delay(3000); 
    lcd.noBlink();
    lcd.cursor(); 
    delay(4000); 
    lcd.noCursor();
    lcd.clear(); 
 }
```

[image: Schematic]

[image: Photo of hardware 1]

[image: Photo of hardware 2]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with a schematic. The schematic tool here is a breeze to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Comment: It’s good practice to include schematics and/or code with your question. You assert your code and connections are correct but you do not include them so we just have to guess. Did you test your Arduino and your display separately?

Comment: Have you checked the contrast pin of your LCD, if the contrast is close to 0, you will never see what you print.

Comment: Proteus is a simulator. It skips a lot of details and it lets you do things in absolutely stupid ways that would normally fail to work in real life. So it is extemely unlikely that the display is broken, it is far more likely that the problem is in your code or connections to the display. Post the code and schematics to see where the issue is. Also picture of the built hardware to see if it matches the schematic or not.

Comment: I have found that displays like yours need time to initialize themselves. Try adding a delay of 0.3 seconds at initial runtime and then communicate with the display.

Comment: @Reroute If the display was turned on, and the contrast pin would be 0V, the characters would be black. Currently, either the display is not even initialized to on, or if it is initialized to on, the contrast is not 0V.

Comment: sanjeev - I have edited the question to fix the display of the newly-added code (by adding "code fences"). I also removed the duplicate display of the schematic and added back the original photo of the display. Finally, I fixed some grammar to help readability. Please check to make sure that everything you wanted to include is now there, and check that I didn't change the meaning of what you said.

Comment: Now that the OP has supplied code, schematic and photos of their hardware, I'm voting to re-open the question.

Comment: @sanjeevsharma, From your photos it looks like you have reversed the order of the data bit lines from the Arduino to the LCD module.

Comment: @sanjeev - Hi, Regarding your update to the question: "*Thanks for everyone issue is solved..i buy new LCD and everything is fine*" I'm glad you solved the problem! However (a) The website does not know your problem is solved, just from that text. It only knows a problem is solved, when an answer is "accepted" (green tick). (b) Originally, there was also the problem found by *Dan1138* too, of the reversed wiring between Arduino and LCD module. Therefore I recommend that you accept the answer from *Dan1138* to recognise the problem that he solved, as well as to mark the question as "solved".

Comment: @SamGibson How to mark a question "solved"?

Comment: @sanjeev - Hi, You asked: "*How to mark a question "solved"?*" I tried to explain in my last comment, a question with an accepted answer is effectively marked as solved (as you have now done here, thanks) and the site won't "nag" readers to answer it, as the question is believed to be solved. You can see some more details here: "[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)" and "[What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)". Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of contrast adjustment the photo show pin 3 is connected:

[image]

But as others have commented the Original Poster needs to edit the question to add more details about what has been connected to what and example code that proves that when the controller code changes a signal that change reaches the LCD module.

**EDIT**

Sanjeev,

This is the Arduino sketch I got to work:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7);

void setup() {
    lcd.begin(16,2);
}

void loop() {
    lcd.print("Sanjeev");
    delay(3000);
    lcd.setCursor(2,1);
    lcd.print("LCD is working");
    delay(3000);
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.blink();
    delay(4000);
    lcd.setCursor(7,1);
    delay(3000);
    lcd.noBlink();
    lcd.cursor();
    delay(4000);
    lcd.noCursor();
    lcd.clear();
}
```

This is how I connected my Arduino UNO:

[image]

This is it running:

[image]

**EDIT 2**

@sanjeev-sharma, From your photos it looks like you have reversed the order of the data bit lines from the Arduino to the LCD module.

Comment: @SamGibson Again same problem, I recheck connection and code but still got nothing. should I go with new lcd ?

Comment: @sanjeevsharma - Hi, I would write my own short troubleshooting answer if the question was open. until then, I'll just give a few thoughts: "*Again same problem*" So you have a problem with your setup, that *Dan1138* doesn't have. "*should I go with new lcd ?*" That is one option, but I can't say that you *should* do that, as I don't know all your constraints. So apply troubleshooting skills - which parts can you check in other ways? Which parts can you swap with other, known-good parts? How can you visualise signals? You could solve this in 5 mins with a cheap logic analyser (or scope).

Comment: @sanjeevsharma, Can you post a clear, close up photo of the connections between the Arduino and the LCD module?

Comment: @Dan1138 Sir, I share a photo of my connection. Please check it.

Comment: @sanjeevsharma, The LCD module data bits look to be in the correct order. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: @Dan1138 yes, sir and pin3 is connected to resistor, resistor is further connected to 
 -ve terminal. I'm going to try with new lcd

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear in the image you have taken and also you didn't provide us enough information, but by the looks of it i think pin number 3 is not connected to anything which is the pin for setting the Contrast. Try connecting it to the circuit supply via a potentionmeter (Don't connect it directly to the supply) and then rotate the knob until you can see the text on your LCD screen.

Comment: thanks for suggestion sir,

Comment: but pin 3 is connected to potentionmeter, male header pin is solidered to wire..